# How to update undefined fields with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working with mongoose, and was wondering if it was possible to update a document, whilst not overwriting any fields that are already set. For example, if the schema is changed. Unfortunately, I can't hardcode the values to update, as I want this to work for all situations.

Here's my current code - `GuildStore` being a constructor which returns an object populated with all of the schema's default values.

```
const updatedGuild = await this.guildStore.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, new GuildStore(), { upsert: true });
```

Comment: I wonder if you could use the aggregation pipeline syntax for defining the changes for the update and leverage the `$mergeFields` operator in there to accomplish your goals